# How can I play Video Files using VLCJ and JavaFX?

Tags: java, video, javafx, vlc, vlcj

I'm aware that JavaFX has it's own media player, but I do not know if it can play MP4 files.
Even if it could, I would still prefer to use VLCJ as VLC supports more formats and varieties than I can count in my near-catatonic state.

I've followed the example posted by Caprical in his VLCJ-JavaFX GitHub but it does, well, nothing.
It doesn't error, but it does nothing.

Looking into the code, it seems the issue is in the Timeline event handler:

```
private final EventHandler<ActionEvent> nextFrame = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        Memory[] nativeBuffers = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().lock();
        if (nativeBuffers != null) { //<-----This is always NULL so everything in the block is skipped . . . 
            // FIXME there may be more efficient ways to do this...
            // Since this is now being called by a specific rendering time, independent of the native video callbacks being
            // invoked, some more defensive conditional checks are needed
            Memory nativeBuffer = nativeBuffers[0];
            if (nativeBuffer != null) {
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = nativeBuffer.getByteBuffer(0, nativeBuffer.size());
                BufferFormat bufferFormat = ((DefaultDirectMediaPlayer) mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer()).getBufferFormat();
                if (bufferFormat.getWidth() > 0 && bufferFormat.getHeight() > 0) {
                    pixelWriter.setPixels(0, 0, bufferFormat.getWidth(), bufferFormat.getHeight(), pixelFormat, byteBuffer, bufferFormat.getPitches()[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().unlock();
    };
};
```

It's been suggested I get the logs but that will have to wait as I'm slipping into unconsciousness as I make this post (when I return to the land of the living, I will see about what I can do to post some). If there is a better way to make this happen, I'm all for it if someone can direct me there. Thanks...

Comment: nativeBuffers is always null because your video isn't playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vlcj-javafx sample on the Github project works just fine.

You say in your question that vlcj "doesn't error, but it does nothing".

Well, there are two ways to check for errors which you don't show in the code you posted in your question.

1. The `mediaPlayer.playMedia()` method returns a `boolean` to say whether VLC accepted your MRL or not - did you check the return value? Note that even if this method returns true, it does not categorically mean VLC could play your media, but if it returns false it categorically means it could not be played.
2. You should add a `MediaPlayerEventLister` to your media player and provide implementations for "playing()" and "error()". These callbacks will be triggered asynchronously - because that's how LibVLC works - only then can you conclude whether vlcj "doesn't error", or "does nothing".

I suspect your media failed to start, probably because of a wrong filename.

Comment: Okay, I have it pointing to the correct location now, but Play is returning false, and I'm getting the error "Failed to create native media resource for 'C:/path/to/video.mp4'"

Comment: Okay, nevermind. Turns out it doesn't much care for '/' in the path. Thank you.

Comment: You need to realise that the path is actually passed to a *native* function - so while Java allows you to use "/" or "\" interchangeably for filenames on whatever platform, that is *not* so for native functions. On Windows you *must* use "\" and on Linux you *must* use "/".